# powershell script for deleting all secrets from azure key vaults

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Looking for a Powershell script which will delete all secretes present in an given azure key vault.
I don't want to delete entire key vault, just want to delete secretes present in it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service

Answer (score 0):

Use Remove-AzKeyVaultSecret, Remove-AzKeyVaultCertificate & Remove-AzKeyVaultKey

Answer (score 0):

With some powershell and the Azure CLI you can achieve this

```
az keyvault secret list --vault-name ${keyVaultName} | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object { az keyvault secret delete --vault-name ${keyVaultName} --name $($_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)  }
```

What it does is

1. Get all the secrets from the fault name
2. Transforms the response into objects
3. For each item take the name from the object and run the az keyvault secret delete command.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Danny van der Sluis tries to delete all secrets at once in one command, which doesn't seem to work. Putting this in a ps1 script worked for me:

```
$SECRETS = az keyvault secret list --vault-name "mysupersecretvault" | ConvertFrom-Json;  
$SECRETS | Select-Object -Property Name | ForEach-Object { az keyvault secret delete --vault-name "mysupersecretvault" --name $_.Name  }
```

After this, you might want to purge your vault in case you want to remake some secrets using the same name. I found it easy enough to do this through the Azure Portal, but you can also use this command:

```
az keyvault key purge --name "mykeyname"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yesman's version worked well for me, however, the purge command should be for secrets, not keys so if you want to delete and purge all secrets this works:

```
$SECRETS = az keyvault secret list --vault-name "mysupersecretvault" | ConvertFrom-Json;  
$SECRETS | Select-Object -Property Name | ForEach-Object { az keyvault secret delete --vault-name "mysupersecretvault" --name $_.Name  }
$SECRETS | Select-Object -Property Name | ForEach-Object { az keyvault secret purge --vault-name "mysupersecretvault" --name $_.Name  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tenantId = "" 
$resourceGroup = "" 
$keyvaultName = ""

# Login
az login -t $tenantId

$allSecrets = az keyvault secret list --vault-name $keyVaultName | 
ConvertFrom-Json                        

foreach($item in $allSecrets)
{
  az keyvault secret delete --name $item.name `
                          --vault-name $keyvaultName

  az keyvault secret purge --name $item.name `
                         --vault-name $keyvaultName       
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?